# Java fails to automatically infer generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

I have this method defined:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> NavigableSet<E> navigableSet (List<E> l)
```

When I write:

```
NavigableSet<Integer> set = Sets.navigableSet(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Everything is fine, but if I write this instead:

```
NavigableSet<Integer> set = Sets.navigableSet(new ArrayList<>());
```

Java is unable to automatically infer the Integer type. I get the following error:

```
error: no suitable method found for navigableSet(ArrayList<Object>)
NavigableSet<Integer> set = Sets.navigableSet(new ArrayList<>());
                                ^
method Sets.<E#1>navigableSet(List<E#1>) is not applicable
  (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: E#2
    equality constraints(s): E#3)
```

Why? What is preventing Java from making a correct inference?

My version of Java is:

```
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You may need to write `Sets.<Integer>navigableSet(new ArrayList<>());`

Comment: This is becase Covariance https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-java-generic-types-covariance-and-contravariance-88f4c19763d2/ if you can, specify concrete ArrayList in navigableSet  method or convert ArrayList to Array on calling method

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. `NavigableSet<Integer> set = Sets.navigableSet(new ArrayList<>());` compiles just fine, and the inferred type argument to `navigableSet` is `<Integer>`. What is your java version?

Comment: Under Oracle JDK 11 the same error appears.

Comment: Well, I get it to fail when building with maven. But the Eclipse compiler infers it correctly.

Comment: @ernest_k Interesting. It compiles fine for me using OpenJDK 11.0.2 and OpenJDK 13.0.1 (i.e. `javac`). The IntelliJ editor also shows no issue.

Comment: As asked, I added the exact java --version in the question